# Retrieving bytes of String returns different results in ObjC than Java

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, mobile

I've got a string that I'm trying to convert to bytes in order to create an md5 hash in both ObjC and Java. For some reason, the bytes are different between the two languages.

Java

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
("78b4a02fa139a2944f17b4edc22fb175:8907f3c4861140ad84e20c8e987eeae6").getBytes()));
```

Output:

```
[55, 56, 98, 52, 97, 48, 50, 102, 97, 49, 51, 57, 97, 50, 57, 52, 52, 102, 49, 55, 98, 52, 101, 100, 99, 50, 50, 102, 98, 49, 55, 53, 58, 56, 57, 48, 55, 102, 51, 99, 52, 56, 54, 49, 49, 52, 48, 97, 100, 56, 52, 101, 50, 48, 99, 56, 101, 57, 56, 55, 101, 101, 97, 101, 54]
```

ObjC

```
NSString *str = @"78b4a02fa139a2944f17b4edc22fb175:8907f3c4861140ad84e20c8e987eeae6";
NSData *bytes = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSLog(@"%@", [bytes description]);
```

Output:

```
<37386234 61303266 61313339 61323934 34663137 62346564 63323266 62313735 3a383930 37663363 34383631 31343061 64383465 32306338 65393837 65656165 36>
```

I've tried using different charsets with no luck and can't think of any other reasons why the bytes would be different. Any ideas? I did notice that all of the byte values are different by some factor of 18 but am not sure what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Java is printing in decimal, byte by byte. Obj C is printing in hex, integer by integer.

Referring this [chart](http://ascii.cl/conversion.htm):

```
Dec Hex
55  37
56  38
98  62
...
```

You'll just have to find a way to output byte by byte in Obj C.

I don't know about Obj C, but if that NSLog function works similar to printf() in C, I'd start with that.

Comment: I knew it had to be something like that. So when I create my md5 hash, you're saying they both need to be created from the decimal or hex value and not be different between the two languages?

Comment: I can't say about ObjC, but the Java `Arrays.toString()` function works by converting your byte sequence to decimals and printing an array of them. Which of the two outputs is your intended one? Modify the other according to that.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html)

```
unsigned char aBuffer[20];
NSString *myString = @"Test string.";
const char *utfString = [myString UTF8String];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes: utfString length: strlen(utfString)];

[myData getBytes:aBuffer length:20];
```

The change in bytes can be due to Hex representation. The above code shows how to convert the string to bytes and store the result in a buffer.

Comment: And this answers the question in which way? Please add some explanation instead of just posting code. I cannot see that it has anything to do with what the OP asked.

Comment: I don't know what is unclear in the code snippet. It clearly shows the right way to convert a string to bytes

Comment: Then maybe it's just because I don't know ObjC. Sorry for that. Nevertheless, your added explanation makes it much easier to understand what the code does.

Comment: No problem @TobiasBrösamle, Thanks :)